# debugging an inproc com server running in dllhost.exe

Tags: c++, windows, com

I am writing an inproc com dll that runs in the dllhost.exe surrogate, but I am running into an issue debugging it.

if there were multiple dllhost.exe's running at once, it would be annoying to find the right one to attach a debugger to. Is there an easy way to identify yours if a lot are running?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your questions separately. That way, you'll get the best possible answers for both of them (instead of a response that only answers one of the questions, or answers one question well and the other poorly). It makes voting easier, it makes it easier for you to select the best answer, and it gives more opportunity for you (and others) to earn reputation points. Click the "edit" link, remove the final paragraph, and paste it as a new question.

Comment: You are giving yourself lots of good reasons to create your own surrogate.

Comment: separated it into 2 questions, the other is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542443/generating-dmp-files-from-an-inproc-com-dll-running-in-dllhost-exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) has convenient feature that allows you to look at which processes have loaded which DLLs. You can also do a search for DLLs in all running processes.

Sysinternals also has a command line utility called ListDLLs (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656) that should work for you.

Once you find the PID of the process that has your DLL, you can attach to it.

Comment: Be sure to only answer this question if you know what "COM surrogate" means.

Comment: @Hans: I don't see how figuring out which processes have loaded a particular DLL is any different with COM surrogates. As far as I can tell, the methods above should still work. Rather than just implying that an answer is incorrect, please state the reason why you believe it is incorrect. The comment will be more useful that way.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative strategy. Just don't try to identify which to attach to. Set a breakpoint in your code and attach to all dllhost.exe processes - when a breakpoint is hit that process will pause under debugger.